# Google Playstore App Transfer

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

I have moved the android app from dev account1 to dev account2 and it is successfully listed in playstore.

However the app still uses the gcm/analytics services registered from account1.

Now I want to add the gcm/analytics services using account2. For that i need to register the new project in account2 to use the integrated services.

Will registering the same pakage with new account would have any impact on the older apps published from account1 and using google services[gcm/analytics] using account1? I just want to make sure the older gcm/analytics is not broken.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks